# Show Chatter feeds related to a Knowledge Article on Salesforce Community

Tags: visualforce, community, visualforce-component, articles

I'm trying to show the chatter feeds related to the knowledge article using chatter:feed component on visualforce page. I'm able to show the feeds successfully to all the internal users but it gives me "Insufficient Privileges' error when any external user who has got 'Read' access to the knowledge article, tries to access the same page on salesforce community. When I removed the chatter:feed component from my visualforce page, the community users are also able to view all the article related information.

Is there any way we can show the chatter feeds related to a knowledge article on salesforce communities (for external users who has got access to the knowledge article)?

Comment: knowledge:articleRendererToolBar visualforce component can be used